# How can I include my argument in {% include %} tag django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

```
    {% if type == "Cryptography" %}
        {% include 'Cryptography/_____.html' %}
    {% elif type == "Password Cracking" %}
        {% include 'PasswordCracking/_____.html' %}
    {% endif %}
```

In a template, I want to include some HTML pages with 1.html 2.html 3.html which are inside C and PC directories. I have tried like this where the page is my argument variable.

```
    {% if type == "Cryptography" %}
        {% include 'cryptography/'{{page}}'html' %}
    {% elif type == "Password Cracking" %}
        {% include 'PasswordCracking/'{{page}}'.html' %}
    {% endif %}
```

View for this

```
def lessons(request, foo, page):
    return render(request, 'lessons.html', {'type': foo, 'page': page})
```

**Note: type and page are my arguments**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter to concatenate strings

```
{% if type == "Cryptography" %}
    {% include "cryptography/"|add:page|add:".html" %}
{% elif type == "Password Cracking" %}
    {% include "PasswordCracking/"|add:page|add:".html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, man you saved my time. But you have forgotten "." in ".html"